# Delete from UITableView using an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is populated through a NSFetchedResultsController. When the user slides an item to the right I have a delete button appearing so that he/she can remove the object using the following approach:

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //perform similar delete action as above but for one cell

    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"User delete: %@", [user displayName]);

    //delete from fetchController
    NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];
    int userStatus = [[user sectionNum] intValue];


    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
```

But when I do that there is an exception because I am not updating the model which is my fetchedResultsController. The question is how to remove from the fetchedController using the indexPath that I have from the commitEditingStyle ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using `NSFetchedResultsController` you only need to delete the object from the context, and it will pick up the change and delete the rows for you.

So remove the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` line and call this instead:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext deleteObject:user];
```

Comment: I get:


Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (11) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: @user1845360: You have to delete the object, but you must *not call* `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. That is done later in the FRC delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974740/delete-row-in-table-view-with-fetchedresultcontroller) , what you have to do is delete an NSManagedObject from your database as well as from the NSFetchedResultsController.